# Is there a standard downloadable calendar event format?

Tags: calendar

I'm looking for a standard calendar event? One that you can download and it puts the event into your Google or Outlook calendar? Something equivalent to vcard for contacts?

Any advice would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, **iCalendar**. 
Here are more infos, though it all can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar

- iCalendar data files are **plain text files** with the extension .ics or .ifb
- iCalendar is a standard ([RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545))
- [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) content type is text/calendar

Example:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
...
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's called iCalendar. Google Calendar supports the iCalendar format, for example.

Comment: upvoted your answer because you were the fastest :-)